# Determining Linear Combinations

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\vec{u}=[2,2,3]^T$ and $\vec{v}=[3,2,1]^T$. Find a vector $\vec{w}$ that is NOT a linear combination of $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$.

My work thus far/ my line of thinking:

Since the vectors are in the form $[x,y,z]^T$, that is, there are three (not sure what to call them- elements?) within the brackets, it means that the vector is in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Since the vector is in $\mathbb{R}^3$, it follows that at least one of the standard basis vectors, $\vec{i}=[1,0,0]^T, \vec{j}=[0,1,0]^T, \vec{k}=[0,0,1]^T$ are linear combinations of $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$.

I chose to deal with $\vec{k}$ in this particular problem. So, is $(0,0,1)=x(2,2,3)+y(3,2,1)$, for some $x,y$? To test it out, I solved the system, which yielded no solutions.

Does that mean there are no vectors $\vec{w}$ that are a linear combination of $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$?

Comment: So you are looking for a $w$ such that for all $a,b\in\mathbb R$, $w\neq av+bu$?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct: you showed that the equation $(0,0,1)=x(2,2,3)+y(3,2,1)$ has no solutions, so this means that the vector $(0,0,1)$ is not a linear combination of the given $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$.

> Does that mean there are no vectors $\vec{w}$ that are a linear combination of $\vec{u}$   and $\vec{v}$

No. You have shown that the vector $(0,0,1)$ is not a linear combination of $\vec{u}$   and $\vec{v}$. But there might be some other vector $\vec{w}$ that **is** a linear combination of $\vec{u}$   and $\vec{v}$. For example the vector $\vec{w} = (5,4,4)$ is certainly a linear combination of $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ --- in fact, it is $\vec{u} + \vec{v}$.

Comment: Ah, ok. So I'm just looking for one linear combination that doesn't work, even though there are possibly many that do work?

Comment: Also does this mean that I didn't have to use one of the standard basis vectors, and could've used any $[a,b,c]^T$ as long as it wasn't a linear combination of $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$?

Comment: Yes. That's what the question asks for.

Comment: Yes, you could have used any vector, as long as you don't get unlucky and pick one that happens to be a linear combination of the two given ones. If you pick any vector at random, there is a very good chance that it will work for you. Choosing one of the standard basis vectors is good (if it works) because it makes the numbers easy.